# OWASP CRS 3.0 paranoia level ignored in custom ruleset

Tags: owasp, mod-security

I'm working on using the new CoreRuleSet 3.0 from OWASP and encountering a situatation where the paranoia level is being ignored and all rules in a file run.

In the CRS-SETUP config file there is a block setting a paranoia level:

SecAction \
 "id:900000,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:tx.paranoia_level=2"

Then there is an include of

992_PARANOIATEST.conf
which contains:

```
SecRule TX:PARANOIA_LEVEL "@lt 4" "phase:3,id:992017,nolog,pass,skipAfter:END-PARANOIA-992"
```

SecRule TX:PARANOIA_LEVEL "@lt 4" "phase:4,id:992018,nolog,pass,skipAfter:END-PARANOIA-992"

# Paranoia Level 4 (apply only when tx.paranoia_level is sufficiently high: 4 or higher)

SecRule ARGS "(walrus)" \
    "phase:2,\
    id:992100,\
    capture,\
    logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR} PARANOIA_LEVEL =  %{tx.paranoia_level}',\
    tag:'testing rule block walrus',\
    log,\
    tag:'paranoia-level/4',\
    block"

SecMarker "END-PARANOIA-992"

In a form field I put the word walrus and I'm blocked, the log shows that this rule fired and that the paranoia level is still 2, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

As I was reviewing the question before clicking post I saw the light. I probably copied the Paranoia Level boilerplate from Response (phase 3&4), but my rules are phase 2 rules (Request). Fixing the Phases with the paranoia level skipping blocks fixed the problem.